# Multi-machine Vagrant networking set up failing

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I've set up multi-machine Vagrant with two boxes, `rails` and `mysql`. Both machines are up and running perfectly. However, I'm having some trouble with the networking:

```
rails.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

mysql.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
mysql.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

Intending to connect to the `mysql` VM, here's my `database.yml` configuration:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: ********
  password: ********
  host: 192.168.50.4
  port: 3306
```

I'm expecting to be able to access the running Rails app (port 3000 on the guest) on a browser (port 3000) on the host but this isn't happening. I'm instead blasted with Chrome's `This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` screen. But when I `cURL` the app from within the guest machine itself, I get a response.

Also, I'm under the assumption that since I've explicitly defined the IP and forward port of the `mysql` box, and used those same values as connection parameters in `database.yml`, connection to the VM should occur with no problem at all. Apparently I'm mistaken because the connection isn't going through. When I test the connection from the MySQL client shell, I get this `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.50.4' (111)`

What is going on?

Comment: so what do you get when you hit `192.168.50.4:3000` ? blank page, error, please detail

Comment: You mean, the result of pinging the Rails app? When I do that, I get both the request and response details in the console log.

Comment: I mean from your browser ? you said `but this isn't happening` so not clear what is happening instead

Comment: Oh. That was for pinging the app within the guest machine itself. As for hitting `localhost:3000` on my browser, I get Chrome's `This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` message.

Comment: and `mysql --host=192.168.50.4 --port=3306 --user=myname --password=mypass` ?

Comment: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.50.4' (111)`

Comment: you probably start mysql on 127.0.0.1 which is by default - edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and make sure to have `bind-address = 192.168.50.4`. Also since you assigned an private and fixed IP you do not need port forwarding